# unresolved 'main' and 'mPreview' in Android camera example at java2s.com

Tags: android, android-camera

I'm trying to work a camera preview example at

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/Hardware/Camerapreview.htm

I copied the following code

```
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

public class PreviewActivity extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    Camera mCamera;
    SurfaceView mPreview;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mPreview = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.preview);
        mPreview.getHolder().addCallback(this);
        mPreview.getHolder().setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

        mCamera = Camera.open();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mCamera.stopPreview();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mCamera.release();
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
        Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
        List<Camera.Size> sizes = params.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
        Camera.Size selected = sizes.get(0);
        params.setPreviewSize(selected.width,selected.height);
        mCamera.setParameters(params);

        mCamera.startPreview();
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mPreview.getHolder());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        Log.i("PREVIEW","surfaceDestroyed");
    }
```

and also at layout activity_man.xml

the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <SurfaceView
    android:id="@+id/preview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I get errors  at the following lines:

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);

     Preview = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.preview);
```

main and preview cannot be resolved

How can I correct this:

thanks

Dave

Answer (score 1):

If name of the layout file is activity_man.xml, then you should call it right.

> setContentView(R.layout.activity_man);

Comment: thanks, the actual code is main not man so that is not the problem.

Comment: I've got everything to work except the ine                            Preview = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.preview);